# jQuery select up to span with specified string

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count the amount of yes's up to a specific span specified by :contains(certain sring). I basically just want to search the first half of this group of questions for how many yes's there are. Here's the code I have tried:

```
<div class="ce-modal-container">
    <div class="ce-cf-container">
      <span class="ce-cf-html-label">Have you chosen your exit path and/or successor?:</span>
      <span class="ce-cf-html-field"> Yes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ce-cf-container">
      <span class="ce-cf-html-label">Have you chosen your exit path and/or successor?:</span>
      <span class="ce-cf-html-field"> No</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ce-cf-container">
      <span class="ce-cf-html-label">Have you done well this quarter?:</span>
      <span class="ce-cf-html-field"> No</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ce-cf-container">
      <span class="ce-cf-html-label">Have you chosen your exit path and/or successor?:</span>
      <span class="ce-cf-html-field"> Yes</span>
    </div>
    <div class="ce-cf-container">
      <span class="ce-cf-html-label">Have you chosen your exit path and/or successor?:</span>
      <span class="ce-cf-html-field"> Yes</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var spanYes = $("span.ce-cf-html-field:contains('Yes')"),
    secondHalf = $("span.ce-cf-html-label:contains('done well')"),
    searchtxtall = spanYes.length;
    searchFirstHalf = $(".ce-cf-container").nextUntil(secondHalf).spanYes.length;
console.log(searchtxtall); //should return 3
console.log(searchFirstHalf); //should return 1
</script>
```

Thanks in advance I know it's a lot of code.

Comment: What is the output of your current code? What's wrong with it currently, in other words?

Comment: the console.log(searchFirstHalf); is returning nothing at the moment

Comment: I am getting similar error in chrome Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined, the selection comes back empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution that's a little less fancy:

```
var count = 0;
$(".ce-cf-container").each(function () {
   if ($(".ce-cf-html-label:contains(done well)", this).length) {
      //break out of loop
      return false;
   }
   if ($(".ce-cf-html-field:contains(Yes)", this)).length) {
      count++;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- You misspelled "container"
- Why do `.nextUntil().spanYes`?  The `.spanYes` doesn't make sense/does nothing
- `.nextUntil` works with siblings, but `.ce-cf-container` is the container.  Try:

  `$(".ce-cf-container span").nextUntil(secondHalf).is(spanYes);`

Comment: I apologize for the misspell, but I tried this and it is returning undefined

Comment: @fentech sorry, try using `.filter` instead of `.is`, and use it on the selector of `spanYes`, not on the jQuery object of `spanYes`.

Comment: hmm it seems to be counting every yes on the page instead of stopping at the specified string

Comment: @fentech sorry again, I wasn't thinking.  the `.container` class contains each span individually, I'm not sure you can use `.nextUntil` like that

Comment: Do you know of any other method i could use to stop half way through the list?

Comment: @fentech you could restructure the html (even just temporarily), but my other solution should work with what you have

Comment: I can't restructure, rather i should say i don't want to, because i'm using someone elses app and adding feature onto it, or i would say yes , it would have been a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help but here's the solution I found.

```
var $secondHalf = $(".ce-modal-container .ce-cf-container:lt(2)"),
    $searchFirstHalf = $secondHalf.find($spanYes).length;
```

in case you wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably drop down more rather than relying on jQuery selectors. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/hRVQK/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answers = [];
    $('.ce-cf-html-field').each(function () {
        answers.push($(this).text().indexOf('Yes') != -1);
    });
    var half = Math.round(answers.length/2);
    var answersFirstHalf = answers.slice(0, half);

    var countFirstHalf = 0;
    $(answers.slice(0, half)).each(function () {
        if (this == true)
            countFirstHalf++;
    });

    var count = 0;
    $(answers).each(function() {
        if (this == true)
            count++;
    });

    console.log('count', count, 'count first half', countFirstHalf);
});
```

​